# Check that gitlab branch has changes before running jobs

Tags: bash, gitlab, git-bash, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ci-trigger

In order to stop the current default Gitlab behaviour of starting pipelines on branch creation I am trying to add a check in each job so that only merge requests trigger jobs when they have changes.

This is what I got so far:

```
  rules:
    - if: '[$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"] && [! git diff-index --quiet HEAD --]'
```

I am not quite familiar with bash which is surely the problem because I am currently encountering a 'yaml invalid' error :d

PS: Is there maybe a better way to do this instead of adding the check to each task?

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges

Comment: Is your goal to disable pipeline execution when a new branch is created?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it can be useful, but Gitlab-ci provide the `only` job keyword that you can combine with `changes` and insert a path to files, in this way you can execute jobs only if there are changes on the code you are interested on.

Example

```
docker build:
  script: docker build -t my-image:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG .
  only:
    refs:
      - branches
    changes:
      - Dockerfile
      - docker/scripts/*
      - dockerfiles/**/*
      - more_scripts/*.{rb,py,sh}
      - "**/*.json"
```

DOC: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlychanges--exceptchanges

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem I had with this approach is that "**/*" seems to be invalid, so I have to specify all extensions and that'd be delicate. I did have one draft with
- "*.{severalTerminationsHere}"
- "**/*.{severalTerminationsHere}"
But if we forget some type or introduce a new one we'll have to modify this in all related jobs :S

Answer (score 0):

> I am not quite familiar with bash which is surely the problem because
> I am currently encountering a 'yaml invalid' error :d

The issue seems to be with

```
[! git diff-index --quiet HEAD --]
```

You can `not` use bash syntax in Gitlab `rules` but to `script` section you can, as the name implies

> In order to stop the current default Gitlab behaviour of starting
> pipelines on branch creation

If this is your goal I would recommend the following rules

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA == "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
```

Let's break down the aforementioned rules

The following rule will be `true` for merge requests

```
if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
```

---

The predefined variable `CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA` will be populated with this value `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`, when you create a new pipeline or a merge request

Therefore, the following rule will `stop` the execution of a `new pipeline and of a merge request`.

```
- if: $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA == "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  when: never
```

`BUT` the merge requests are accepted from the previous rule, taking into account how gitlab evaluates them.

Quoting from https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#specify-when-jobs-run-with-rules

*Rules are evaluated in order until the first match. When a match is
found, the job is either included or excluded from the pipeline*

---

Finally, the following rule will be true for a new pushed commit

```
- if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
```

---

> PS: Is there maybe a better way to do this instead of adding the check
> to each task?

The aforementioned rules `dont` have to be added for each job, but instead are configured once for each pipeline take a look
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/workflow.html

Basicaly, add the `workflow rules` statement at the start of your gitlab.yml and you are good to go

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated reply. I will try this and update

Comment: Yeah it works like a marvel

Comment: If it indeed works, please approve the answer and upvote. For future users to know that this fixed the problem. If you don't know how check this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow

Comment: I am reopening because when you do git push and then create an MR, the pipeline is not triggered

Comment: @ifrances you are correct, the ordering of the rules i proposed was not correct. Updated answer and added more explanations. Please check again